# Xcode archive error with RestKit framework

Tags: objective-c, xcode, restkit

I'm just getting started with Objective C and RestKit.

I created an application and added the RestKit project. I use RestKit to load en map JSON data from my webserver.

The application runs fine in the simulator and on my iPhone device. Now I want to create a TestFlight beta. I have setup a distribution certificate and added it to my phone and Code Signing settings.

Now I want to generate the IPA. I use the Archive option under the Project menu item. When I click's this button occurs the following error:

> ```
> Ld: in /Users/japak/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AlquinApp-ahkxhlzmjpdjjbczzkyriizvchid/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/AlquinApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/libRestKit.a(RKJSONParserJSONKit.o),
> mach-o string pool extends beyond end of file for architecture armv7
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ```

Comment: I have no experience with RestKit but I have found that Linking to an external library within an iOS app is problematic for archiving. I had to incorporate the library into my workspace and build it as part of the workspace to be able to archive it.

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue with a few dynamic frameworks from Cocoapods in a Swift 3/Xcode 8.2 project.  A deep clean of the build folder (Product -> (hold option key) -> Clean Build Folder) fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

my solution was to uncheck the "Parallelize Builds" Option under "Schemes => Edit Schemes => Builds => Build Options". 
(I saw this under Xcode 6.3, I am sure this option is also in older versions existent)

Answer (score -2):

I think the problem is because you are using something which should not be used for distribution and it's currently protected by NDA?

Comment: I have removed the RestKit library and replace it with AFNetworking. Now it's works.

Comment: Oh, cool. I got the same error as you did and that was because of the reasons I wrote in my answer.

Comment: How does something being under NDA impact the build process of a target application?  This answer makes no sense for the error in question.